How to prove the set-valued function is continuous?
I have such a set-valued function based on a probability simplex:
$$
\Omega(r^*) = \left\{r \middle| {1}^T r_i = 1,~ r_i \geq 0,~ \forall i\in [I];~ 0\leq r_{is} \leq \gamma_{is}(r^*),~ \forall s\in \mathcal{S}_i,~ i\in [I]\right\}, 
$$
where
$$
r = [r_{is}]_{s\in \mathcal{S}_i,~ i\in [I]},~r_i = [r_{is}]_{s\in \mathcal{S}_i},
$$
$\gamma_{is}\in [0, 1]$ is a continuous function of $r^*$, and $\operatorname{dom}\Omega$ is a probability simplex.
By definition, a set-valued function is continuous if and only if it is both upper and lower semi-continuous at every point in its domain. However, to check the semi-continuity, by definition, we need to consider every open set $V$ for every point $r$ in the probability simplex such that $\Omega(r) \subset V$ (upper) or $\Omega(r) \cap V\neq \emptyset$ (lower).
This made me confused about how to start, because it is difficult to enumerate "every" open set. So I'd like to know whether there are some propositions based on the definition I can employ to prove the continuity of $\Omega$?

What is $[I]$, what are the $S_i$?

@copper.hat They are finite set of indices. $[I] = {1, 2, 3, \dots, I}$ and $\mathcal{S}_i\subset \mathcal{S} = {1, 2, 3, \dots, S}$.

You need more conditions to ensure that $\Omega$ is lsc. For example, take $[I]={1}, S_1 = {1}, \gamma_{11}(r) = r$. Note that $\Omega(1) = {1}$, but $\Omega(r) = \emptyset$ for $r<1$.

@copper.hat What if there always exist an $s\in \mathcal{S}i$ such that $\gamma{is}(r) \equiv 1$? Or $\Omega(r)\neq \emptyset$ for all $r\in \operatorname{dom} \Omega$?

I'm not sure what you are asking. The question you asked has a simple counterexample. If you have further assumptions, you should add them to the question.
